# EXCEL VBA FOR inside IF

Tags: vba, excel

Never used VBA before and basically just trying write this sub:

```
Sub Populate_Empties()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim k As Integer


' test for 50 rows...then change i from 2 to 278970


m = 2


    For k = 3 To 8
        For i = 2 To 50
            If (IsEmpty(Cells(i, k).Value)) Then
                m = i 'any statement
            Else
                j = i - 1
                For n = m To j
                    Cells(n, k).Value = Cells(i, k).Value
                m = i + 1
            End If
End Sub
```

I keep getting error End If without Block

Any suggestions?

Comment: `For`s need a `Next` where the code is supposed to loop.  You are missing 3 - `Next`s

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by completely altering the question.  Raise a new question if you have a new issue.

Comment: And when you do raise the new question, you will need to include more than Maldred's code and the comment that "I still can't get the code to populate my worksheet".  You will probably need to show the data that is being used, and tell us what you are trying to achieve, so that we can work out **why** the code isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing statements on your for loops

```
Sub Populate_Empties()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim k As Integer


' test for 50 rows...then change i from 2 to 278970


m = 2


    For k = 3 To 8
        For i = 2 To 50
            If (IsEmpty(Cells(i, k).Value)) Then
                m = i 'any statement
            Else
                j = i - 1
                For n = m To j
                    Cells(n, k).Value = Cells(i, k).Value
                Next n
                m = i + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Those things annoy me, and I hate upvoting answers that annoy me. LOL

Comment: Note that the identifier after the `Next` token, is entirely optional/redundant.